# "Please let me know if you have any questions" in japanese

Tags: translation, formality

I'm trying to send a report to my superior, and want to say "please let me know if you have any questions" about this report.
The only form that I can think of is "何か質問があれば言ってください".
But I am sure it is very casual.
So what is the best formal way to say so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for your replies. I ended up asking my superior how to say it formally and properly. He recommended the following:

"疑問点、コメント等がありましたら、ご教示いただければ幸いです".

Thanks again for your help

Comment: that's interesting wording yet makes plenty sense. sort of the equivalent to "I would be happy to learn of any comments or concerns that you may have"

Answer (score 3):

My ordinary template is:

> ご不明な点が<sub>(a)</sub>ありましたら<sub>(b)</sub>ご連絡ください<sub>(c)</sub>。

- For the (a) part:

  > ご質問が
  >   （何か）わからない（点／ところ）が
  >   お気づきの点が (~ "if there is something")

  will also do, but I prefer my choice above being terse and wide coverage. Note that 質問 means "question-asking" and doesn't primarily stand for questions in your mind.
- (b):

  あれば is also grammatically sound but a bit less formal. You could use ございましたら for your client, but I don't feel it's needed for your in-company superior (unless you're in a big company and sending to executives).
- (c):

  > お知らせください

  will also work. 言ってください is not business-like as you said. If you want more euphemism saying "I'd appreciate —", replace ください with いただけ（ると／れば）幸いです.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of using いってくだい I think 知らせてください would be more natural.  Otherwise,

> 何か質問があれば知らせてください。

is good.

知らせる means "to let someone know".  Yet, my language skills are a bit weak when it comes to using appropriate keigo and such to a superior.

> 何か質問があればお知らせになってください。